# selector for checkbox in script mvc

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

Good day, 
I have a view with this code

```
<ul id="check-list-box" class="list-group checked-list-box">

            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.RespuestasParaDetalleRespuesta.Count(); i++)
            {
                <li class="list-group-item" data-color="danger">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Something[i].Id)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Something[i].DetailId)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Something[i].IsSelected,new { @class="test"})@Model.Something[i].SomeText
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
```

I also have my script that changes each checkbox propertie "checked"

```
   $(function () {
        $('.list-group.checked-list-box .list-group-item').each(function () {
            var $widget = $(this),
                $checkbox = $('.test'), //I use this selector but is not a good one
                ....
                more settings
                };
            $widget.css('cursor', 'pointer')

            // Event Handlers
            $widget.on('click', function () {
                $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked')); //changes propertie to checked
               ...more code
                ...more code
            });
```

As you can see, with this code once the user clicks on an item, the function tries to change a checkbox propertie to checked or unchecked.
However I realized that this approach is not working because when I click on one item, all checkbox are checked.

The id of each checkbox is like the following

```
Something_0__IsSelected , Something_1__IsSelected
```

what should I do to make the $checkbox selector more specific? thanks

**addition**
This is how my view looks, I would like to check each checkbox when I click on a row
[image]

Comment: Just `var $checkbox = $(this);`

Comment: sorry, but if I use $(this); will it work? since I already used var $widget = $(this)

Comment: Sorry, its not clear what you doing - do you have multiple `<ul>` elements? Why do you have an `$.each()` on the `<ul>` - aren't you wanting to loop the checkboxes?

Comment: use `this` to refer to the current checkbox `$widget.on('click', function () {
                $(this).prop('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked')); `

Comment: I am trying to use a more specific selector than using a class to select a checkbox, for instance, can I use the Id as selector?

Comment: What do you mean _click a row_ - did you mean a `<li>` element? in which case you use a relative selectors (e.g. `var checkbox = $(this).find('.checkbox');` (and add `class="checkbox"` to your checkboxes)

Comment: @StephenMuecke , yes it was what I was trying to do. Thanks a lot! can you post an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$checkbox = $('.test')` is selecting all checkboxes. You need to select just the checkbox within the appropriate `<li>` element

```
$('.list-group.checked-list-box .list-group-item').each(function () {
    // $(this) is the <li> element
    var $widget = $(this), 
    $checkbox = $(this).find('.test'), // change this
    ....
```